# My Joomla website admin panel suddenly has no menus available after I refreshed messages

Tags: administrator

I'm using j3.4.8 and suddenly after I changed the Special ACL to include Manager, and I went back to it after dinner, Joomla displayed "Refreshed Messages" button, which upon clicking produced Profile without any admin panel menu visible at all. Please can anyone help me so that I can have the admin menu displayed again.

Thank you..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly did you change and on which component in the backend?

Comment: Do you have acces to php myadmin? I think can help you

Comment: Your issue seems similar to this one: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16923/unable-to-access-my-site - You will need to restore the ACL of your site and have a Super User account that have viewing access everywhere in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the nested tree model of your menu table got corrupted. This happens because of wrong left and right values assigned to the rows in your table. The main reasons could be:

- You have manually deleted rows from xxx_menu table
- Some extension that you installed or using corrupted your table entries

To fix, try:

- Go to Menu manager
- Click rebuild button

Answer (score 1):

check out your acl table, it may happen that way that super admin was excluded from special ACL